# Check if list contains mixed types

Tags: python

I tried to write a function in Python, which would check if a list contains mixed object types(e.g. a list containing a list **and** a string). I could manage checking the list once but not the sublists.
The function should return True if a list contains **only** lists or **only** strings.

For example:

`[["aa", "bb", "cc"], ["aa"], [ ]]` - would return `True` 
`[["aa", "bb"], [["aa", "bb"], "aa"]]` - return `False`(there's a list containing a list AND a string)

Checking a list once:

```
def same_type(lst):
    # an empty list would return True
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return True
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        for l in lst :
            # check if other elements are the same as first
            if type(lst[0]) != type(l):
                return False

        return True
```

**EDIT:**
I ended up doing this:
1) Find all the lists(sublists) in the given list with recursion and put them in one big list.
2) Iterate over that big list and check if there is a list with mixed datatypes with my `same_type` function.

Comment: Maybe you could first flatten the list

Comment: This is a bit awkward since lists and strings are different types themselves. So you want a special case for lists, if a value is a list then check its contents recursively?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking for (`[["aa", "bb"], **[["aa", "bb"], "aa"]**]` isn't a valid expression). Doesn't your proposed solution do what you want?

Comment: Your list is made of lists. Do you mean to check whether the items of the sublists are all of them same type?

Comment: @skyking My html(bold) was edited to python. No it wouldn't work, it would only check the outermost lists [[list1],[list2]] and give out True, but the list2 contains mixed types [[list], str]]

Comment: In your second example, the outermost lists are `["aa", "bb"]` and `[["aa", "bb"], "aa"]`, which are both of type `list`. However, the items of the *sublists* are not. Is this what you want to test for? Because the word outermost is not clear.

Comment: Yes, I want to know if there is a list or sublist somewhere containing mixed types.

Comment: Do you any of the answers provided so far solve your problem? Is it possible for a sublist to further contain another list, so you'd have to check the types of the subsublist?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that lists are treated as a special case, and their contents need to be examined recursively; other iterators (like tuples, or even strings) are not treated like that.

First, a function that recursively finds the first non-list element (or raises ValueError if there aren't any):

```
def find_first_element(L):
    if not L:
        raise ValueError("list is empty")
    item = L[0]
    if type(item) == list:
        try:
            return find_first_element(item)
        except ValueError:
            # That sublist was empty, maybe the rest of the list
            # contains something...
            return find_first_element(L[1:])
    else:
        return item
```

Then a recursive function that checks if all items in the list have the same type as the first one:

```
def all_same_type(L):
    try:
        first_item = first_find_element(L)
    except ValueError:
        # Nothing in there, so all the same
        return True

    return all_of_type(L, type(first_item))

def all_of_type(L, first_item_type):
    for item in L:
        if type(item) == list:
            # Recurse
            if not all_of_type(item, first_item_type):
                return False
        elif type(item) != first_item_type:
            return False
    # We saw all and didn't return False, so return True.
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten your list first, through a function like this:

```
def flatten(lst):
    outp = []
    for elem in lst:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            outp += flatten(elem)
        else:
            outp.append(elem)
    return outp
```

However, keep in mind that it's considered unpythonic to care what an object's type is, as long as it does what you want it to do. (Look up duck-typing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following recursive function that checks that all elements in the list `lst` are of type `typ` or lists which satisfy the same property.

```
def all_type_eq(lst, typ):
    # an empty list would return True
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return True
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        for l in lst :
            # check if other elements are the same as first
            if type(l) == list:
                if not all_type_eq(l, typ):
                    return False
            elif typ != type(l):
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to need to do then is to flatten your list before checking:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for e in lst:
        if type(e) == lst:
            for ee in flatten(e):
                yield ee
        else:
            yield e
```

Then you just check if there's a type mismatch:

```
def mixed_types(lst):
    t0 = None

    for e in flatten(lst):
        if t0 is None:
            t0 = type(e)
        elif type(e) != t0:
            return False

    return True
```